# How to limit the number of messages from RabbitMQ to spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, rabbitmq, spark-streaming

I am getting all the messages from the RabbitMQ when the connection is established. I want to limit the number of messages fetch the RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1):

You can set following parameter

> maxMessagesPerPartition   - Maximum number of messages

See [spark-rabbitmq](https://github.com/Stratio/spark-rabbitmq) for more details.

Hoping this helps.

Comment: Yes we have the spark properties but the problem here is RabbitMQUtils.createStream(ssc, rabbitMQConnection). I am setting queueName, host,port,virtualhost,username and password. If i try to set the MaxMessagesPerPartition  in the rabbitMQConnection parameters. It is saying that there is no method with that signature. I am not sure where to set this property.